# Send token to reset password via email in url [Laravel Passport]

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport

I have a method to send an email in case the user loses their password, the email is sent and I have configured a notification for a custom url in an Angular view. But my question is about how I can send the token in the url, for example `http://localhost:4200/password?token={TOKEN}` or another similar way. So far i have this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Notifications;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Lang;

class MailResetPasswordToken extends Notification
{
    use Queueable;
    public $token;

    public function __construct($token)
    {
        $this->token = $token;
    }

    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return ['mail'];
    }

    public function toMail($notifiable)
    {
        return (new MailMessage)
        ->subject(Lang::get('Change password'))
          ->line('You are receiving this email because we received a password reset request for your account.')
         ->action('Reset Password', url('http://localhost:4200',[$this->token], false))
         ->line('If you did not request a password reset, no further action is required.');           
         ->action('Reset Password', url(config('app.url').route('password.reset', [$this->token, $notifiable->email], false)))
   
    }

    public function toArray($notifiable)
    {
        return [
            //
        ];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could send token in a url with the following code.

```
$url = url('/password?token=' . $this->token);
```

Finally, you pass `$url` into `->action()`.

Example:

```
<?php

namespace App\Notifications;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Lang;

class MailResetPasswordToken extends Notification
{
    use Queueable;
    public $token;

    public function __construct($token)
    {
        $this->token = $token;
    }

    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return ['mail'];
    }

    public function toMail($notifiable)
    {
        $url = url('/password?token=' . $this->token);
        return (new MailMessage)
          ->subject(Lang::get('Change password'))
          ->line('You are receiving this email because we received a password reset request for your account.')
          ->action('Reset Password', $url)
          ->line('If you did not request a password reset, no further action is required.');
   
    }

    public function toArray($notifiable)
    {
        return [
            //
        ];
    }
}
```